# Grace notes at beginning of "A Media Luz"

Tags: notation

I'm trying to transcribe some part of "A media luz" from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvtiM48eKHI).

Here it is what I did:

[image: A media luz - beginning]

I'm wondering if there is an alternative way to notate the first four notes. Could I use graces notes or would they be inappropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the urge to notate the opening as grace notes, but in fact they're just regular sixteenth notes. Try conducting the first few measures to get a sense of the tempo, then go back and listen to the very beginning. You'll notice that the first four pitches take the span of an entire quarter note, whereas your current notation has them lasting only the span of an eighth note.

[image]

Comment: I make it a 3 beat anacrucis, so crotchet rest, and all you've written in the remaining part of the bar. What do you think? That's if it's the intro part OP means.

Comment: I agree with Tim

Comment: Richard, you're right, I listen it again and they are 4 regular sixteenth!

Comment: Now, let's suppose that I want to play in my way, so 4 32th. Would it make sense to notate them as grace notes?

P.S. I also think like you that the "real" piece start with f d f a and the previous four notes (f g gis a) are an anacrusis.

Comment: @G.Lari - they're certainly not grace notes, as Richard says. Grace notes take uo the timing of other notes, and here, they're notes in their own right, written as semiquavers, taking up a whole beat.

Comment: @Tim - Thank you for you last comment, ok!

Regarding what you said at beginning (3 beat anacrusis) I remember I saw some edition of this piece that starts exactly like that (and some notate them as a mordente)

Comment: @Tim Oh my goodness, you're correct. I'm not sure how I messed that up...thanks!

Comment: @Tim - What do you mean with "That's if it's the intro part OP means" ?

Comment: @G.Lari I think he just meant "assuming we're talking about the same spot."

Comment: @G.Lari - there are several anacruces and I hoped that we were discussing the very first one, at the very beginning. I guess we were.

Comment: @Tim - I was talking about the first 2 second of the video. 

After that, (from second 2 to second 4) it should be: 
r8 \tuplet 3/1 {a8 ( b a)} (using lilypond language)